# Login Loop on Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS, multiple computers, tty3 doesn't work

Tags: login

I have control of two Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS computers, one at home and one at my church. Both have become stuck in a pernicious login loop. I've searched for instructions but all say to break out by logging in to tty1 or tty3. That doesn't work, it just starts yet another login loop for the tty terminal. Recovery mode does the same thing. Apparently this started after a recent software update, because the computer at church gets very little use and no new software has been installed or configuration changes made in months. Help in resolving this issue would be very much appreciated.

For what it's worth I can access the file system if I boot from the installation DVD-ROM, but I'm unsure of the changes to be made while not running on the main system HDD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: What do you mean by a "login loop"? It appears from what your saying, the graphical login does not work, neither does a tty login. Do you get a login prompt? Can you login as a different user? What happens when you log in to the graphical or tty terminal? Please provide more details in your question so we can help you.

Comment: By "login loop" I mean that I get the normal login prompt, whether from the GUI or tty. I log in with proper user credentials, and then I immediately get the login prompt again. No chance to enter a command or do any troubleshooting. I'm using the correct credentials; if I enter an invalid password I get the usual error. But when correct, I get told to log in again. Same results with any valid user name.

Comment: If you can access the file system, have you confirmed that the disk is not full? 

Comment: The disk was less than 25% full. I ended up having to reinstall Ubuntu. Fortunately most of my important data was backed up to my NAS.